# Stopping an running SKAction - Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skaction

The following code will animate a rotation.

```
let something:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode()

func start(){
  let rotateAction = SKAction.rotateToAngle(CGFloat(M_PI), duration: 10.0)
  something.runAction(SKAction.sequence([rotateAction]))
}
```

Now I want to stop the animation within the animating duration. Is there anything similar to the following? I want to stop the animation when the user touches the screen.

```
func stop(){
  something.SKAction.stop()
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just have to use either:

1. `something.paused = false // or true` to pause actions on the node
2. `something.removeAllActions()` to definitely remove actions associated to the node
3. name your action when launching `something.runAction(action,withKey:"action1")` and then `something.removeActionForKey("action1")` to remove a given action

You may also change the speed if needed.

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, run the action with a key so you can identify it later:

```
something.runAction(rotateAction, withKey: "rotate action")
```

Then you can stop it later by calling

```
something.removeActionForKey("rotate action")
```

Alternatively, you can remove all actions also

```
something.removeAllActions()
```