# How to disable Timer in Spritekit in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

i want to animate images randomly in grid so i have taken Timer.

This is my code :

```
 id wait = [SKAction waitForDuration:self.initialTimerValue / 1000];

id run = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    //My Custom Method
}];
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[wait, run]]]];
```

i want to disable timer on Touch Event,how to invalidate timer ?
Can you please Help ?

Comment: You can use the method `invalidate`, described here: [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415405-invalidate)

Comment: @FabioBerger i am not using NSTimer.so how to invalidate it?

Comment: What are you using instead of NSTimer? Please describe such important things in your post, otherwise it will he hard to give you a good answer.

Comment: @FabioBerger i am using SKAction which i describe in question.that is code to run timer. or any other way to run timer in scenekit?

Comment: Ok if I understand correct, you want to stop the action that repeats forever?

Comment: @FabioBerger yes stop and pause

Comment: Check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502326/stopping-an-running-skaction-sprite-kit

Comment: @FabioBerger worked for me.thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stopping an running SKAction - Sprite Kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35502326/stopping-an-running-skaction-sprite-kit)

Comment: @FabioBerger how to pause action using SKAction